# What printer properties should I change to print in a diferent paper? (29mm x 90mm, 62mm x 100mm, etc)

Tags: delphi, printing, vcl

I have an application that allows the user to print labels, but the user may have different papers to print (for instance I am running tests on 62mm x 100mm label rolls so I print on those, but I also have smaller rolls which are 29mm x 90mm).

My question is, what property of the DevMode^ should I be modifying? 
should I set : `DevMode^.dmPaperSize := 271;` (is not predefined but the printer supports that paper)

or `DevMode^.dmDefaultSource := something;`

I don't know exactly which of those I need in order to configure the paper that the user selected so that printer's configured paper matches with the size (lets say 271), the width (lets say 90mm) and height(lets say 29mm).

thanks for any help privided.

Comment: You use `dmDefaultSource` to chose which paper source will printer use. This comes useful only on printers with multiple trays. As for defining paper size you use `dmPaperSize` to chose one of the predefined paper sizes. For more information about possible values check [DEVMODEA MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-devmodea). Alternatively you can set custom paper size dimensions using `dmPaperLength` and `dmPaperWidth` fields. If you do so then you should leave `dmPaperSize` field empty

Comment: Thank you @SilverWarior. I had no clue on leaving dmPaperSize empty for custom paper.